# mysql get data from one table to another, while grouping records and extra fields

Tags: mysql

ok, i will explain first what i have, and what i need as result.

basicly, i have a phonebook, but the phonebook has duplicate records for "company"
while the duplicate records are not exactly duplicate... :\

i think an example will explain better:

demo records:

```
1. Company A, Address A, Phone A
2. Company A, Address A, Phone B
3. Company A, Address A, Phone C
4. Company A, Address B, Phone A
```

what i want, is to make a new table, which will be filled with all "Company A", "Address A" phone numbers into one records, so the result should be something like:
Company A, Address A, Phone A, Phone B, Phone C etc..

The second problem is that "company A" can be also a bit diffrent, example:

```
 1. Company XYZ, Address A, Phone A

 2. Company ABC, Address A, Phone A
```

i dont even know how to start with this.
i was thinking of doing it by coding some c# application,
but i think there might be an easier solution by using pure mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your way does not maintain normalization,
however, the following might what you are looking for

**create new table:**

```
create table new_table
(
  company_a varchar(255),
  address_a varchar(255),
  phone_a varchar(255),
  phone_b varchar(255),
  phone_c varchar(255)
); // define your index
```

**insert into new table:**

assuming phone does not contains `,`

```
insert into new_table
select 
  company, 
  address, 
  substring_index(group_concat(phone), ',', 1) 
    as phone_a,

  substring_index(
    substring_index(group_concat(phone), ',', 2), ',', -1
  ) as phone_b,

  substring_index(group_concat(phone), ',', -1)
from 
  old_table
group by company, address;
```

Comment: sorry, i dont even understand your answer :) , i tried compiling it as is, but got an error on the second substring. Shame on me :(

Comment: `as phone_a,` instead of `as phone_a`

Comment: MySql workbench is returing an "Lost Connection" while excuting.

Comment: this is a 1.5 M records table, i try to run it now from command line.

Comment: i have let the query run all night,
and when i woke up i so this error:
ERROR 1260 (HY000): %d line(s) were cut by GROUP_CONCAT()
any suggestion ?

Comment: no choice, extract company by company will avoid this problem

Comment: company by company ? your talking about over 150k of companies... :(

Comment: anyway, i have tried it with smaller amount of data ( like 'a%' ) 
and it seems to work, so i will mark this as answered.
thx ajreal.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an answer but a different approach

Why not have

- A table company

`company | company_id | ...`

- A table address

`address_id | company_id | ...`

- And a table phone

`phone_id | address_id | ...`

This way you can have as many addresses per company and as many phone numbers per address without having to change your SQL schema in the future

Comment: You edited your question as I was replying by adding the "second problem" portion. This adds a many to many relationship where there was previously only a 1 to many relation. It would require adding an extra table to map addresses to and from companies

Comment: well, i understand what your direction is,
but the results are going to serve for "leaflet" marketing.
eace company, in a diffrent address are supposed to get an offer by post.
so, i need to keep them seperated as records, but each record should contain as much fields about "Company A" in "Address A".
All this is integrated into a new software i develope for a client.